# location.reload(true) starts an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am using javascript function for refreshing PHP page. I have used `location.reload(true)` method to reload page from server, but the page reloads in an infinite loop.
This is my code:

```
<div id="modalEdit" class="modaln">
    <div class="contenu_modal">
        <span class="closeBtn">&times;</span>
        <center><h2>Modifier le Module</h2></center>
        <form action="modules.php" method="POST">
            <div class="inputBox">
                <input type="text" id="txtEditModule1" class="txtEditModule" name="module_id_edit" readonly required>
                <input type="text" id="txtEditModule" class="txtEditModule" name="module_name_edit" required>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" id="btnEditModule" class="btnEditModule" name="btn_mdf_module" value="Modifier">
        </form>
    </div>

    <?php
    if (!empty($_POST['btn_mdf_module'])) {
        $p1=$_POST['module_name_edit'];
        $p2=$_POST['module_id_edit'];
        $n=modifier_module($p1,$p2);
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>location.reload(true);</script>";
    }
     ?> 

</div>
```

PS: I tried to use `header("Location:modules.php")` PHP method but it doesn't work neither.

Comment: **method to reload page from server**, perhaps the browser keep seeing the `location.reload` even after reloading the page.. be sure to check the page source..

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to accomplish? A proper explanation would help

Comment: @charlietfl i want to update some data in mysqli database using modifier_module($p1,$p2) method in a modal-form but when i submit the page won't refresh

Comment: if its a modal, and you want to keep it on screen, how about just emptying the form fields. no need to reload it

Comment: What does that have to do with `location.reload()`? Confused

Comment: @smith thank you for your answer this helped me